# Xamarin Solution Keeps looking for Non-existant Class

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I've been doing a proof of concept using Xamarin Android.

I opened the solution today and it was not longer working. So, I started removing stuff. I got it right down to bare bones where I was just trying to show a simple view with a button.

But for some reason, it is still throwing an exception about a class I first commented out, then removed completely:

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: licensingApp.droid.views.ShowLicencesFragment
```

There is absolutely no reference to that fragment in the solution. The text does not exist in the solution. I removed the view (xaml) file as well.

But for some reason, Xamarin is still tripping up on it.

I've done all the usual things :
- clean
- build
- clean
- rebuild
- close then re-open Visual Studio

But still, this pesky exception preventing the Main view from showing.

Any way to solve such weirdness?

The funny thing is, it is bombing out on the exact same line number as before in the MainViewmodel, but the code is totally different and not relevant to an exception being thrown there. It's as if it *thinks* the code is how it used to be. Feels like a tooling fail to me.

Comment: Try deleting the `obj/Debug` `obj/Release` directories to remove the "leftovers" that `/Target:Clean` does not remove

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, but that suggestion did not work. Looks like I have to create a whole new solution again, which is not really acceptable.

Comment: Try deleting Resource.Designer.cs from the Android project and rebuilding

Comment: @onefootswill, try uninstall the app/apk from your device/emulator and rebuild -> deploy. Are you using Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio? Additionally, does your android project have Shared Runtime and Fast Deployment enabled? From the sound of things it seems that the assemblies are out of sync.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got past this block in the wee hours by downloading the Visual Studio emulator and using that. For some reason, that ensures the current code is being used. So, the one that comes out of the box Android_Accelerated_86 should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by swapping emulators from the out-of-the-box Android emulator which came with Xamarin to the hyper-v [Visual Studio emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/). For some reason, that ensures the current code is being used. So, the emulator that comes out of the box **Android_Accelerated_86** should be avoided.

The Visual Studio emulator is really good and there are some pretty good tools around interacting with it.